# Manipulate Child Process within Script being Started by a Grunt Task

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs, child-process

I have a script which is being run through a grunt task.

Within this script, I need to start and then eventually stop a child process from running in the background.

If I run the script (or scripts) which manipulate these child processes without grunt, all works fine - so script/s run, child processes are spawned and then killed etc etc - but with grunt this fails and the child process being spawned, is killed a few seconds after...

I know you can create async child process spawning tasks within grunt, but I need to spawn/kill child processes within the scripts themselves.

Any ideas?

Comment: With what grunt task is your script launched?

Answer (score 0):

When grunt finishes its build, its process ends, terminating all its children process. Your script is probably launched as a child process, so this is what you will need to change.

Please give more details on how you're launching it for more detailed help.